# get statistics web pages in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

whats the best way to get Statistics Web pages  by the users visited ?

anybody may explain how do we implement to get statistics web pages by the each users visited
and the most page is visited?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either use a 3rd party software like GA or Piwik or write a front controller which run before Controller and logs every request in DB. I prefer GA.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way seems to be [Google Analytics view helper](http://www.zfsnippets.com/snippets/view/id/30/google-analytics-view-helper).

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to use [Piwik](http://piwik.org/):

> Piwik is a downloadable, open source (GPL licensed) web analytics software program. It provides you with detailed real time reports on your website visitors: the search engines and keywords they used, the language they speak, your popular pages… and so much more.

It's build on top of ZF and MySql.

Why? Because collecting WebStatistics can be quite complex. If your app is not a Web Analytics tool, I suggest not to hack such functionality into the application, but use a standalone tool for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Google analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) and I have no complains for now.